# JoinField_management Appears to Append Field Values

Tags: arcpy, attribute-joins

In the snippet of code below, I'm attempting to create variables, then pass them to the arcpy.JoinField_managment tool:

```
#Set join parameter variables
inFeatures = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
inField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
joinTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
joinField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inFeatures,"inFeatures_lyr") #make feature layer from feature class
#Join road feature class to buffer distance table
arcpy.JoinField_management("inFeatures_lyr", inField, joinTable, joinField)
```

The result appears to actually append the field values from `joinTable` to the attribute table in `inFeatures_lyr`.  I've tried replacing the variables with hard-coded values and get the same result.  I can't remove the join and and can only get the fields out by deleting them as I would any other field in the feature class.  How do I structure this to create the join correctly, do my geoprocessing, then remove the join programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong tool.  You are using **Join Field**, and you want to be using **Add Join**.

[Join Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/join-field.htm) adds the fields to your dataset - it modifies your data.

> Joins the contents of a table to another table based on a common attribute field. **The input table is updated to contain the fields from the join table.** You can select which fields from the join table will be added to the input table.

[Add Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-join.htm) joins the two datasets the same way it does if you create a join within the ArcMap GUI.

> Joins a layer to another layer or table (where layer is a feature layer, table view, or raster layer with a raster attribute table) based on a common field.
>
> The records in the Join Table are matched to the records in the input
>   Layer Name. A match is made when the input join field and output join
>   field values are equal. **This join is temporary**.

You can then follow the Add Join with the [Remove Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/remove-join.htm) tool to remove it programmatically.

Comment: @SDRobinson This looks like a new question - I'd recommend asking as a new question.

Comment: Yes.  That's what I'm going to do.